# less using math in a ruleset for opacity

Tags: css, less

I'm trying to do multiplication for opacity.  I have also tried:  calc(@opacity * 100)

```
@opacity-ruleset {
filter:alpha(opacity= (@opacity * 100));
-moz-opacity:@opacity;
opacity: @opacity;
-webkit-opacity: @opacity;
}
```

How do I make this calculation work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of IE special hacks do not conform to standard CSS syntax (thus Less can't properly parse them), so usually you need [escaping](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-escaping), e.g.:

```
@opacity: .2;

foo {
    @ms-opacity: @opacity * 100;
    filter: ~'alpha(opacity=@{ms-opacity})';
    opacity: @opacity;
}
```